# How to Initialize an array of my object in another class

Tags: c++, class, initialization-list

I am making a game in which my main class for controlling game objects is "inGame".
There will be several other custom made classes composed inside "inGame".

like,

```
class mouse
{
  int x, y;
  bool alive;
  float speed;
  public:
    mouse(int xx, int yy, float spd, bool alv)
    {
        x = xx; y = yy; speed = spd; alive = alv;
    }
    // member functions
};

class inGame
{
  mouse m1; 
  dog d1; // single object which are easy to construct
  public:
    inGame() : d1(200, 400, 1.5, false), m1(40, 40, 0.5, false) //This works fine
    {} //coordinates fixed and set by me
    // member functions
};
```

---

But now lets say I want 3 mouses. So i thought of m1[3] or maybe a vector.

```
class inGame
{
  mouse m1[3]; // like i want 3 mouse(animals) in the game screen
  dog d1; // single object which are easy to construct
  public:
    inGame() : d1(200, 400, 1.5, false) //Confusion here m1(40, 40, 0.5, false)
    {}
    // members
};
```

so I've tried the following:

```
inGame() : m1[0](1,2,3,true), m1[1](2,3,4,true), m1[2](3,4,5,true) { } //NO
inGame() : m1 { (1,2,3,true), (2,3,4,true), (3,4,5,true) } { } //NO
inGame() : m1 { (1,2,3,true), (2,3,4,true), (3,4,5,true); } { }
```

even if I use std::vector m1 then how to I initialize through the inGame default constructor? Would it be writing inside the constructor?

```
mouse temp(1,2,3,true);
m1.push_back(temp);
```

Which is the better approach?
in main I will just do:

```
inGame GAME; //Just to construct all animals without user requirement
```

Thanks.

UPDATE:

no luck with

```
inGame() : m1 { mouse(1,2,3,true), mouse(2,3,4,true), mouse(3,4,5,true) } { }
inGame() : m1 { {1,2,3,true}, {2,3,4,true}, {3,4,5,true} } { }
```

There an error after "m1 {" that "expected a )". And m1 { "}<--" that "expected a ;"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use brace-enclosed initializers:

```
inGame() : m1 { {1,2,3,true}, {2,3,4,true}, {3,4,5,true} } { }
```

Without C++11, you will need to use a container such as `std::vector<mouse>` and populate it inside the body of the constructor, or using a function that returns  suitably initialized one:

```
std::vector<mouse> make_mice()
{
  std::vector<mouse> v;
  v.reserve(3);
  v.push_back(mouse(1, 2, 3, true));
  v.push_back(mouse(2, 3, 4, true));
  v.push_back(mouse(3, 4, 5, true));
  return v;
}
```

then

```
inGame() : m1(make_mice()) {}
```

where `m1` is now an `std::vector<mouse>`

Comment: But if you don't have C++11, then you can't use list-initialisation at all.

Comment: Ummm, its still not working. I added an edit in the end. VC++ 2010 is showing a red line on both m1's { }. How do i check which C++ verison im using?

Comment: It's not really that simple, unfortunately. Different compilers support different subsets of newer functionality. You'll have to consult your compiler version's _documentation_ to find out what it does and does not support. Shocking, I know!

Comment: @juanchopanza is copying a vector very fast like in m1(makemice). Or should I directly push_back into m1, if there's a difference?

Comment: @ShoaibHaider There should be no perceptible difference as the copy is likely to get elided. But you should profile it if you think it could be a problem.

Answer (score 5):

Assuming you're using C++11 or later,

```
inGame() : m1{{1,2,3,true}, {2,3,4,true}, {3,4,5,true}}
{}
```

This will work whether it's a regular array, `std::array`, `std::vector`, or any other sequence container.

If you're stuck with an ancient dialect, then initialisation will be more problematic. Using a vector, and calling `push_back` in the constructor as you describe, is probably the least nasty approach. To use an array, you'd need to give `mouse` a default constructor, then reassign each element in the constructor.

Comment: +1 I didn't see the disparate construction values. nice answer.

Comment: Ummm, its still not working. I added an edit in the end. VC++ 2010 is showing a red line on both m1's { }
And "least nasty approach" = best approach?
How do i check which C++ verison im using?

Comment: @ShoaibHaider: A compiler from 2010 probably won't support a language from 2011, so it sounds like you are indeed stuck in the past. "Least nasty" = "best, if you really can't switch to a modern compiler".

Comment: Ok, so if i update to VC2013, i would be using C++11 right? Thanks for all the help

Comment: @MikeSeymour Thanks for all the help, both responses were good, couldnt decide who to give the correct answer tick.